# Why do we have no meta Sheriffs?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, badges, per-site-meta

On Arqade, the following badges have been awarded:

[image: EVERYONE LOVES MAGICAL TREVOR]

And here are the corresponding badges awarded on meta:

[image: 'COS THE TRICKS THAT HE DOES ARE EVER SO CLEVER]

There seems to be a discrepancy here, you can be a meta-constable, but not a meta-sherriff. The situation seems to be the same on a few other sites I've checked, including SO (where there are no constables).

Is this a bug?

Comment: Well, as far as I know the elections are for the parent site only. The assignment of the elected mods on the child meta is manual process done by the team.

Comment: Either way, Grace Note wasn't awarded Constable on either site. *grump*

Comment: @Shadow Nope, as a site mod you're automagically a mod on the child meta, although you do have to agree to a separate (yet identical)  mod agreement.

Comment: On [su], [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], [security.se] there are no Constable or Sheriff badges on meta.

Comment: Because Meta is murder and they were all killed in the line of service. *sings "I shot the sheriff, but I did not shoot the deputy"*

Comment: @TimStone `s/deputy/constable/` - it still scans!

Answer (score 12):

There's two ways someone can be promoted to moderator on a site, and please keep in mind that while child meta sites are *linked* to a parent, they are (for all intents and purposes) independent sites (same code, different setup).

The first way is appointed, which creates a user history record, which is what fires the constable badge. If you're *appointed* on the main site, you're automatically *appointed* on the child meta.

The second way to promote you is 'by winning an election', and this reason is *tied* to the elections the main site had. Since there's no election *on* the meta site, you get promoted for winning on the main, and *appointed* on the child meta. No one is ever elected to be a moderator on a child meta site, because the child meta site has an empty election database table.

I'll see what we can do to fix this, *possibly* broaden the award query to see if you have the badge on the parent and trigger it on the child meta, but I have to see what kind of side effects that sorcery might have before we do it.

Comment: FWIW, we do not have a single [Constable badge on meta.cs.SE](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/constable). So your explanation seems to be inaccurate or out of date. (I agree that site mods should get the badge both on main and meta.)

Comment: We have [4 constables](http://superuser.com/help/badges/178/constable) and [14 sheriffs](http://superuser.com/help/badges/179/sheriff) on superuser, with none [for](http://meta.superuser.com/help/badges/89/constable) either [on](http://meta.superuser.com/help/badges/90/sheriff) meta.superuser.